# Problems communicating with external editor in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, macos, qt4

I am writing a command-line Qt4 script (using QCoreApplication) on Mac OS X.

I am using this code adapted from C++ Programming with Qt 4, 2nd ed. p. 313:

```
QTemporaryFile outFile;
if (!outFile.open())
    return;

QString fileName = outFile.fileName();
QTextStream out(&outFile);
out << initial_text;
outFile.close();

QProcess::execute(editor, QStringList() << fileName);

QFile inFile(fileName);
if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    return;

QTextStream in(&inFile);
QString text = in.readAll();

std::cout << text.toStdString() << std::endl;
```

When the above is run with editor set to "/usr/bin/vim", "Vim: Warning: Input is not from terminal" is printed, then vim launches *with* the initial text (the string initial_text); however, I am unable to edit or quit because pressing escape prints a blue ^[ at the position of the cursor, similar to every other key.

When editor is instead set to "/Users/jason/bin/mate" (the TextMate command-line utility), TextMate launches, *without* the initial text.  I can edit and save the document, and when I quit, the application reads in the initial text (which should have been overwritten).

I am puzzled since this code is in a printed book so it should work.  Am I using the wrong strings for the editor variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your editor "/Users/jason/bin/mate" doesn't support a filename being passed as an argument.

From your terminal, try something like:

```
echo "Test text" > test.txt  
/Users/jason/bin/mate test.txt
```

To see if it opens the editor with the right text.

Comment: I figured out that you have to execute "mate -w" to wait for the file to be closed.